# Is there an "escape converter" for file and directory names available?

Tags: bash, escaping, filenames

The day came when I had to write a BASH script that walks arbitrary directory trees and looks at arbitrary files and attempts to determine something regarding a comparison among them. I thought it would be a simple couple-of-hours *tops!* process - Not So!

My hangup is that sometimes some idiot -ahem!- excuse me, *lovely user* chooses to put spaces in directory and file names. This causes my script to fail.

*The perfect solution*, aside from threatening the guillotine for those who insist on using spaces in such places (not to mention the guys who put this in operating systems' code!), might be a routine that "escapes" the file and directory names for us, kind of like how cygwin has routines to convert from unix to dos filename formats. Is there anything like this in a standard Unix / Linux distribution?

Note that the simple `for file in *` construct doesn't work so well when one is trying to compare directory trees as it **ONLY** works on "the current directory" - and, in this case as in many others, constantly CDing to various directory locations brings with it its own problems. So, in doing my homework, I found this question [Handle special characters in bash for...in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563856/handle-special-characters-in-bash-for-in-loop) and the proposed solution there hangs up on spaces in directory names, but can simply be overcome like this:

```
dir="dirname with spaces"
ls -1 "$dir" | while read x; do
   echo $x
done
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** The above code isn't particularly wonderful because the variables used inside the while loop are INACCESSIBLE outside that while loop. This is because there's an implied subshell created when the ls command's output is piped. **This is a key motivating factor to my query!**

...OK, the code above helps for many situations but "escaping" the characters would be pretty powerful too. For example, dir above might contain:

```
dir\ with\ spaces
```

Does this already exist and I've just been overlooking it?

If not, does anyone have an easy proposal to write one - maybe with sed or lex? (I'm far from competent with either.)

Comment: Bash must have one internally, since it gets used whenever you hit "tab", so that might be a starting point.

Comment: I agree and would love to harness it directly - if only there was a way! Hmmm... Maybe some of our Open Source friends might consider it a worthy addition to the shell itself? It could be argued that the original "updates" to permit spaces (in particular) are incomplete without such a tool. ...Meanwhile, I haven't any idea how to replicate programatically the tab  action! You?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your need is. Usually using `find` and a `while` loop is more than sufficient. Maybe you could post some code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: you just have to use quotes around your variables.

Comment: In Bash, you can use process substitution to avoid creating a subshell a loop: `while read var; do something; done < <(somecommand)`

Comment: See the two edits in my answer for additional information.

Comment: You're getting way too salty about spaces in filenames. `touch $'\n'` and you may have a stronger point. Also, I bet the lame-ass coders of decades past were complaining about people naming files with non-8.3 filenames instead of writing proper code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a really nasty filename for testing:

```
mkdir escapetest
cd escapetest && touch "m'i;x&e\"d u(p\nmulti)\nlines'\nand\015ca&rr\015re;t"
```

**[ Edit:** Chances are that I intended that `touch` command to be:

```
touch $'m\'i;x&e\"d u(p\nmulti)\nlines\'\nand\015ca&rr\015re;t'
```

which puts more ugly characters in the filename. The output will look a little different. **]**

Then run this:

```
find -print0 | while read -d '' -r line; do echo -en "--[${line}]--\t\t"; echo "$line"|sed -e ':t;N;s/\n/\\n/;bt' | sed 's/\([ \o47()"&;\\]\)/\\\1/g;s/\o15/\\r/g'; done
```

The output should look like this:

```
--[./m'i;x&e"d u(p
multi)
lines'
re;t]--         ./m\'i\;x\&e\"d\ u\(p\\nmulti\)\\nlines\'\\nand\\015ca\&rr\\015re\;t
```

This consists of a condensed version of **Pascal Thivent's** `sed` monster, plus handling for carriage returns and newlines and maybe a bit more.

The first pass through `sed` merges multiple lines into one delimited by "\n" for filenames that have newlines. The second pass replaces any from a list of characters with a backslash preceding itself. The last part replaces carriage returns with "\r".

One thing to note is that, as you know, `while` will handle spaces and `for` won't but by sending the output of `find` with null termination and setting the delimiter of `read` to null, you can also handle newlines in filenames. The `-r` option causes `read` to accept backslashes without interpreting them.

**Edit:**

Another way to escape the special characters, this time without using `sed`, uses the quoting and variable-creating feature of the Bash `printf` builtin (this also illustrates using process substitution rather than a pipe):

```
while read -d '' -r file; do echo "$file"; printf -v name "%q" "$file"; echo "$name"; done< <(find -print0)
```

The variable `$name` will be available outside the loop, since using process substitution prevents the creation of a subshell around the loop.

Comment: It's not mine but, yes, it's a monster :)

Comment: Great post, thanks. ...This is _very_ good and responsive to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [How to escape file names in bash shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list) while googling that I'm quoting below:

> After fighting with Bash for quite
>   some time, I found out that the
>   following code provides a nice basis
>   for escaping special characters.
>   Of cource it is not complete, but the
>   most important characters are
>   filtered.
>
> If anybody has a better solution,
>   please let me know. It works and it is
>   readable but not pretty.
>
> ```
> FILE_ESCAPED=`echo "$FILE" | \
> sed s/\\ /\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ /g | \
> sed s/\\'/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'/g | \
> sed s/\&/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&/g | \
> sed s/\;/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\;/g | \
> sed s/\(/\\\\\\\\\\(/g | \
> sed s/\)/\\\\\\\\\\)/g `
> ```

Maybe you could use it as starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this code snippet. It's an incomplete version of what I was asking for, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet handles all filenames (those including blanks, quotes, newlines, ...):

```
startdir="${1:-.}"                              # first parameter or working directory

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  IFS is undefined
#  read:
#  -r  do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
#  -d  delimiter is \0  (not a valid character in a filename)
#  done < <( find ... ) . redirection from a process substitution
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while IFS=  read -r -d '' file; do
  echo "'$file'"
done < <( find "$startdir" -type f -print0 )
```

See also this [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: Thanks for the post. OK, this is another way to loop and is neither better nor worse than the loop posted in the original question. It has the disadvantage of resetting IFS and if you need it set inside the loop, you'll have a headache. And it has the advantage of letting the script-writer carry varrible contents out of the loop - a limitation of the code presented in the original query.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty serious problem with the escaping approach: what escapes are needed depends on the context the variable's going to be expanded in, and in the usual case there's no escaping that'll work.  For instance, if you're going to do something simple like:

```
touch a "b c" d
files="a b\ c d"
ls $files
```

...it won't work (ls looks for 4 files: "a", "b\", "c", and "d") because the shell doesn't pay any attention to escapes when it word-splits $files.  You could use `eval ls $files`, but that would fail on things like tabs in the filenames.

The `while ... read ... done < <(find ... -print0)` approach fgm suggested works solidly (and because of the flexibility of find's search patterns, is very powerful), but it's also a rather messy pile of workarounds for various possible problems; if you don't need find's power, it's not hard to get things done with `for` and `*`:

```
shopt -s nullglob    # In case of empty directories...
for filepath in "$dir"/*; do    # loop over all files in the specified directory
    filename="${filepath##*/}"    # You just wanted the files' names?  No problem.
    echo "$filename"
done
```

If (as you mention in the question) you're interested in comparing the two directory trees, looping through one of them isn't quite what you want; it'd be better to put their contents into arrays, like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
pathlist1=("$dir1"/*)    # Get a list of paths of files in dir1
filelist1=("${pathlist1[@]##*/}")    # Parse off just the filenames
pathlist2=("$dir2"/*)    # Same for dir2
filelist2=("${pathlist2[@]##*/}")
# now compare filelist1 with filelist2...
```

(Note that AFAIK the `"${pathlist2[@]##*/}"` construct is not standard, but seems to have been supported in both bash and zsh for a while now.)

Comment: Very thoughtful post and creative, thanks. One point here is that with your escape pattern troubles comment, one could overcome the problems you speak of by using quotes in addition to the "escaping" - at least I think so. ...My system doesn't seen to know what "shopt" is - I presume it's a shell option. My bash doesn't like it! And I'm afraid I don't quite get what the "${pathlist2[@]##*/}" business is even trying to do! More here, perhaps?

Comment: On quoting in addition to escaping: I tried that, the quotes just get treated as part of the filename; aside from `eval`, I don't think there's a way to do it. On `shopt`: what version of bash are you using?  It's in every version I've used...  If you don't have it, and there are no matching files, the glob pattern expands to itself.  An alternative is that you can add `[[ -e "$filepath" ]] || continue` as the first line of the `for` loop.

Comment: On `"${pathlist2[@]##*/}"`: `"${pathlist2[@]}"` expands to the members of the array, each as a separate "word".  Adding `##*/` removes through the last "/" in each entry -- basically, it's a trick for turning an array of full file paths into an array of just the filenames.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, I obviously haven't spent enough time learning shell!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename; do
  echo 'I am doing something with "'"$filename"'".'
done < <(find)
```

Do note that the `<( )` notation won't work when bash is invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The find command sometimes works in this situation:

```
find . -exec ls {} \;
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm necromancing an ancient question, but the fact that none of the answers list this simple and foolproof approach creates an urge to post it.

Simply use `find -print0` and then iterate over its output using `read -d $'\0'` (i.e. using the null byte as an input delimiter).

Example:

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir dragons-be-here
$ cd dragons-be-here

$ # Atrocious filename stolen from the currently accepted answer
$ touch $'m\'i;x&e\"d u(p\nmulti)\nlines\'\nand\015ca&rr\015re;t'

$ find -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
>     printf "FILE: --- %q ---\n" "$file"
> done
FILE: --- $'./m\'i;x&e"d u(p\nmulti)\nlines\'\nand\rca&rr\rre;t' ---
```

As you see, this works perfectly no matter what evils your filenames may contain, since filenames on a Unix system can contain anything except the null byte.