# Looping list of folder path containing comma "," and spaces results in error

Tags: bash, for-loop

The folowing code work great but when the folder path contain "," and spaces make error

```
dir data/ > folder_file.txt

   IFS=$'\n'
for file in "`cat folder_file.txt`"
do
printf 'File found: %s\n' "$file" 
ls  "data/$file/" #-----------> "," and "space" brook this task

done
```

any idea ? to escape special character

it work now any other advice's to make it better

```
 IFS=$'\n'
 a=0


 for file in out/*; do

 ls "$file" > html_file.txt


 for file2 in `cat html_file.txt`; do

 echo $file
 mv "$file""/""$file2" "$file""/""page_"$a
 let a=$a+1

  done
  a=0
  done
```

Comment: ls "some, thing/" works for me... what exact error are you getting?

Comment: ls "A, b, and à /" ls: impossible d'accéder à A, b, and à /: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: Don't take it personally, but you're using several _antipatterns._ And sooner or later your script was meant to break. I don't know where you learned these (broken) techniques, but now you have 2 problems: 1. unlearn them; 2. learn the proper ones. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle special characters in bash for...in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563856/handle-special-characters-in-bash-for-in-loop)

Comment: @filip: gniourf is right, and your script is probably in different encoding than a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you loop on the content of a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for file in data/*; do
    printf 'File found: %s\n' "$file"
    ls "$file"
done
```

We use the shell options `nullglob` so that the glob `*` expands to nothing (and hence the loop is void) in case there are no matches.

Comment: sorry but i wanna use folder_file.txt later with sed '1d' folder_file.txt

Comment: @filip: Why do you want to use that?

Comment: cause when the folder is empty the script dislplay data/A, b, and c/*

Comment: @filip: you fix this with `shopt -s nullglob`.